# how to change colours in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

i'm trying to change my Navigation Drawer items to blue and background to white 
i tried

```
app:itemTextColor="@color/blue"
android:background="#fff"
```

and it give me this 
[image: after changing colors]

and the original view is 
[image]

i wan't to change all the items including the group title and make images appear when i change the background , any help?

**Edit**
my Navigation Drawer

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    android:background="#fff"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/blue"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

my Menu

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/jazeera"
        android:icon="@drawable/jazeera"
        android:title="Al Jazeera English" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/abc_news"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="ABC News (AU)" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bbc_news"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="BBC News" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cnn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="CNN" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/daily_mail"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Daily Mail" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ny_times"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="The New York Times" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/usa_today"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="USA Today" />

</group>

<item android:title="Sports">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/bbc_sport"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="BBC Sport" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/fox_sports"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Fox Sports" />
    </menu>
</item>`<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/jazeera"
        android:icon="@drawable/jazeera"
        android:title="Al Jazeera English" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/abc_news"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="ABC News (AU)" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bbc_news"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="BBC News" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cnn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="CNN" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/daily_mail"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Daily Mail" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ny_times"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="The New York Times" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/usa_today"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="USA Today" />

</group>

<item android:title="Sports">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/bbc_sport"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="BBC Sport" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/fox_sports"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Fox Sports" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: show your full navigationdrawer xml code and your menu xml code

Comment: i edited the question and added them @IbrahimAli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally figured out why it did all of this

- i changed app theme it was a dark theme and headers title was default white so it didn't appear
- i added a property `app:itemIconTint="your desired color"`in the **NavigationView**

  final view [image]